How to prevent parcel from moving images around?
Trying to use webgl to render a texture, and I am using some npm libraries so I am using .cjs files and using parcel to run it. When I try to get the image from my resources file it doesnt work because parcel moves the image into the project directory and also changes the image name. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?
the file structure looks like this:
index.html
index.cjs
src/
  | renderer.cjs
  | resources/
  |   | image.png

but when I run it, parcel changes it to this:
index.html
index.cjs
renderer.cjs
image.86ccfd9d.png

ChatGPT didnt help either

You have to import the image in your renderer code, for example import mytexture from "resources/image.png". Then in the code you have to use mytexture for the rendering instead of the png name. Parcel will make sure the correct image is loaded. If this is not how you want to work, you can look at static file copying with Parcel. Then the image names won't be changed.

thank you so much! Should have thought of that
